# Does a `do-realease-upgrade` delete my files and softwares

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, 16.04

Currently I use Vivid( Ubuntu 15.04 ) and I want to upgrade it to Xenial ( Ubuntu 16.04 ), I know I should invoke `do-release-upgrade` but if I invoke that will my files and softwares ( for example gcc 6.1.0 ) be intact or they will be cleaned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will upgrading Ubuntu remove installed software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788592/will-upgrading-ubuntu-remove-installed-software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. An upgrade (as done by the Software Updater app or through `do-release-upgrade`) is an *in-place* upgrade, meaning that all it will do is update software to the latest version.

In short, your files shall be untouched, and your software and Ubuntu version upgraded.

Comment: And does it upgrade ubuntu version to 16.04 or it just upgrades softwares?

Comment: Sorry for my newbish questions

Comment: @Halo_HeroOfReach Yes, a 'version' only means the new-ness/replacements of packages and software.

Comment: @Halo_HeroOfReach The only purpose of the AskUbuntu community is to help newbies :)