# Will upgrading Ubuntu remove installed software?

Tags: upgrade, release-management

I am planning to upgrade Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 and I was wondering if it will erase the installed software e.g., openCV, Unity Tweak Tool etc.

Comment: If you are using software from ppas (also named: 'unstable', 'stagging', 'canary', etc), and there is no ppa available for the new Ubuntu release, such ppa software will not be erased BUT it might not work anymore. Check for new ppa(s) first. I personally like to use the latest version of Chromium, but in the last three years the ppa has changed like at least once per year.

Comment: Just did upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04,  and yes it will ask you whether or not you want to remove outdated packages. Unity Tweak Tool , specifically, stayed there though

Answer (score 10):

- Upgrading will replace your current software with newer versions of that software.
- An upgrade can go wrong and if the end result is a reinstall your installed software will get removed.
- In theory software could be removed if it is deemed obsolete. Or replaced by something new (open office got replaced by libre office at some point; though the impact of that was minor or close to nothing).
- ALWAYS make a backup of your personal files. Not just when you do an upgrade. Every day. And once every so do a restore to test the backup. Prepare for failure.

Answer (score 2):

I've been upgrading Ubuntu since 10.04 every 6 months and I've never lost any personal files or installed software.

But, after upgrading to Xenial, repositories working with Willy will become deactivated. So, you have to re-enable those repos (or PPAs) and edit the sources with the right information (distro name). You will also have to check if the developers are distributing their packages for Xenial (Launchpad for PPAs)

See snaps here:
[How to activate deactivated repository after upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293091/how-to-activate-deactivated-repository-after-upgrade)