# What is going to happen to my data after the upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

Lately my Ubuntu 16.04 has been asking me to upgrade to a newer version. I wonder: if I upgrade what is going to happen to my data and to the programs I have installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will upgrading Ubuntu remove installed software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/788592/will-upgrading-ubuntu-remove-installed-software) && https://askubuntu.com/q/5435/480481

Comment: Usually nothing bad happens.  But I always recommend that people should make regular backups of data that they consider important.